# Aggregate multiple image class values into a single class (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, clustering, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have created 20 clusters from unsupervised classification of a specific region in Google Earth Engine. Now I want to reclass them. For example, let's say class values 10, 4, and 16 are forest, I want to combine these class values into a class that represents forest. Similarly, I want to do this for water, agricultural land, etc. How can I do that?

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/caaad7c94fc54521aa09e7bf869d69c4)

```
var poi=ee.Geometry.Point([78.032188,30.316496]).buffer(35000);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
                  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31');
var trueColor321 = dataset.select(['B3', 'B2', 'B1']);
var tru=trueColor321.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var truclip= tru.clip(poi);
var trueColor321Vis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.4,
  gamma: 1.2,
};
Map.setCenter(78.032188,30.316496, 9);
Map.addLayer(truclip, trueColor321Vis, 'True Color (321)');

var dataset1=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI').filterDate('2015-01-01','2015-12-31');
var NDVI= dataset1.select('NDVI');
var ndvimean=NDVI.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var ndviclip=ndvimean.clip(poi);
var visparam={
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ]
};
Map.addLayer(ndviclip,visparam,'NDVI',0);


//clustering
var training=ndviclip.sample({
  region : poi,
  scale : 30,
  numPixels : 5000
});
var clusterer=ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(20).train(training);

var result = ndviclip.cluster(clusterer);

Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(),{},"clusters");

var subset= result.select("cluster").eq(4).selfMask();
Map.addLayer(subset,{},'only 19');
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `remap` function. Just to give you an example, here I remapped your band values to ones and other values to zeros.

```
// merge several clusters together

  // Define your from and to values
  var fromForest = [10,4,16]; // original values
  var toForest = [1,1,1]; // values to give to the pixels

  var fromAgricultural = [1,2,3]; // original values
  var toAgricultural = [1,1,1]; // values to give to the pixels

  var fromBuildup = [5,6,13]; // original values
  var toBuildup = [1,1,1]; // values to give to the pixels

  // remap the pixel values and rename the bands accordingly
  var Forest = result.remap(fromForest, toForest, 0, 'cluster').rename('Forest');
  var Agricultural = result.remap(fromAgricultural, toAgricultural, 0, 'cluster').rename('Agricultural');
  var Buildup = result.remap(fromBuildup, toBuildup, 0, 'cluster').rename('Buildup');

  // concatenate to one image
  var image = ee.Image.cat([Buildup, Forest, Agricultural]);

Map.addLayer(image.clip(poi),{},"merged clusters");
```

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/129d1bcd0c896daa6ac4f451f9e02e7d)

Comment: To expand on Kuik's answer a bit... this creates a 3-band image (1 band per class). If you want all final classes in the same band, you can use the described `.remap()` method, just make two corresponding lists: "fromValuesAll" and "toValuesAll" that include corresponding values for all of the changes you want to make.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just choose to store values in different bands so you can conveniently rename them to a user friendly name. If you want to continue you analysis, it's probably better store each class with a different integer value in a single band image.